# bring the arrow outside of carousel and make it responsive on both sides

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the element UI where i am using the carousel. The Problem right now is the arrows are coming inside or cutting from the sides

i tried adding the div around the buttons like this

```
<div class="arrowLeft"><button type="button" class="el-carousel__arrow el-carousel__arrow--left" style=""><i class="el-icon-arrow-left"></i></button></div>
```

the css of the above arrow is:

```
.arrowLeft {
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
```

in firefox, i am able to see the arrow outside

https://prnt.sc/2uIH99dyTaR1

but it on the top but in chrome, it is showing like this

https://prnt.sc/Q-698jcYqTSe but no exactly in middle

in IE, it is like this

https://prnt.sc/GJT5pvESW2Wn

not sure if i use position fixed or not, but i am not 100% confident, on mobile or ipad browsers how it will behave

position the fixed will create problems.

this class `el-carousel__arrow el-carousel__arrow--left` has the position of `absolute`:

Comment: Provide a working example. This can't be answered without the full source.

Comment: let me check if i create a fiddle, i don't think it can be fiddled with vue

Comment: i have a fiddle like this, but somehow it is throwing an error on the export http://jsfiddle.net/6ujep529

Comment: you're using vue.js component. You'll need to figure out how to provide the source code.